# Looking for the name of a card-battle cartoon show

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Looking for a show about a group of three kids/teens who, using cards to change into monsters, fight and recover relics. I believe there are two or three other groups of three also trying to get the relics.

In the main group there are two boys and a girl. The boys were both white, one is from a farm and I don't know where the other is from. The girl was dark skinned and either black or blue hair. The three travelled around the world using a red plane.

I think they only use one monster primarily. The girl uses a monster created from gas and at one point is green. One of the boys uses a metal robot most of the time and at one point is given another better version of that card to use. I believe the episode for this was called something like green with envy.

All I'm getting from the internet is that it may be Chaotic, but that isn't the right show.

I also believe the girl's name was Mai and one of the boys were Ky, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Redakai: Conquer the Kairu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redakai:_Conquer_the_Kairu_(TV_series))*

[image: Series image]

> The series revolves around Ky, a 15-year-old student of ancient martial arts, who embarks on an epic quest to find the Kairu, a primordial alien energy source. Aided by his friends Maya and Boomer, Ky travels the world searching for the Kairu while attempting to make sure that his extraterrestrial teenage alien adversaries don’t find it first

They do summon monsters. Ky Stax summons a robotic creature primarily:

> Ky's signature monster is the Plasma powered Metanoid and its Plasma-Energy Blast and Plasma Swords attacks with the Seismic powered Fractus and its Magma Minions and Boulder Toss attacks rounding out his go-to combo.

Maya indeed has dark skin. Her two primary monsters are Harrier and [Infinita](http://redapedia.wikia.com/wiki/Infinita_-_Green_Elemental), the first of which is green and the second of which looks somewhat gaseous, and sometimes appears as being green:
[image: Harrier - Green monster] [image: Green Infinita - Green Elemental]

The male companion, Boomer does come from a farm.

> He was born on a farm in the Midwest and left at young age left to join his childhood best friend Ky as a student of Master Boaddai.

There is an episode entitled "[Green with Infinita Envy](http://redapedia.wikia.com/wiki/Green_With_Infinita_Envy)", Season 1 Episode 22, which looks to be an episode where Infinita was green.

They do travel in something like a plane, but it's more yellowish. It's named the "[X-Scraper](http://redapedia.wikia.com/wiki/X-Scaper)" in the manga, but is apparently unnamed in the anime.

[image: X-Scraper]

And lastly, while the description does not mention cards, Redakai is [a collectible card game](http://redakai.wikia.com/wiki/Redakai_Trading_Card_Game) which was marketed via the anime.

Comment: Yep, this definitely looks like the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

I found a cartoon that satisfies some of your points.

### [Bakugan Battle Brawlers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bakugan_Battle_Brawlers), a Japanese-Canadian cartoon action adventure

[image: picture]

#### Satisfies

- This would satisfy your point on kids/teens
- At least one of the girls is dark-skinned
- This would satisfy your point on 'cards changing into monsters'

> Dan Kuso's life changed one day when random cards fell out of the sky with special powers. He and his friend Shun invented a game called Bakugan with these. Together with his friends Runo, Marucho, Julie, Shun, and Alice, they form the Bakugan Battle Brawlers and its members are accidentally dragged into fighting for the fate of Vestroia (the Bakugan's home dimension) against the Doom Beings.

- One of the "boys" - most probably main character Dan Kuso - uses 1 robot most of the time

> Drago (ドラゴ Dorago) is Dan Kuso's Guardian Bakugan and the Bakugan main protagonist of the Bakugan Battle Brawlers anime series. He serves as both a battle partner, a guardian, and source of wisdom.

#### Does not satisfy

- There are 6 friends, not 3
- Names are different

Good source website:
[Bakugan Wiki](http://bakugan.wikia.com/wiki/Bakugan_Battle_Brawlers).

Answer (score 2):

*[Redakai Warrior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redakai:_Conquer_the_Kairu_(TV_series))* 
I was looking for it too. This is what it is.

Comment: What about Redakai Warrior matches the information in the question?

Comment: I removed most of what I added to the answer because I was starting to feel that it was inflating the answer far beyond what it began as.