# Cartoon where a group of 3 go around fighting rival teams with magical powers

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

This cartoon is animated and not in CGI or old animation like the 90s. I think it was made in 2009-2014 by Cartoon Network or Kix.

The only things I know is that the cartoon involves a group of 3 people who have magical powers (the team consist of 2 boys and 1 girl and an orange alien with an antenna).
One of the boys has blond hair and white and the girl is dark-skinned.

They go around fighting rival teams with their magic and in the second fight they turn into the magical creatures they gained their powers from.

I remember the blond character saying "freeze ray- what the, freeze ray is a blue attack not a green attack" and the girl character says "you can't hit what you can't see- ha missed".

I remember the orange alien saying "don't eat me- I'm sweaty and my antenna is chewy".

I remember the characters saying the name of the creature and rising up into the air with the image of the creatures behind them (this is in the first fights they do and in the second fights they turn into their creatures)

The orange alien character can use this "magic" as well but he only does it for one or two episodes (one of the rival team characters who is female turns into a spider during their fights).

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Take a moment and [read our tips for story ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62709) and see if it shakes out any more details. This is lacking a lot of details and may not be answerable as-is.

Comment: Mod note: OP [edited in more details](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/243149/4) anonymously, so I approved the edit.

Comment: You might want to follow the [instructions here to merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer (and once you merge your accounts, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: Closed as a duplicate since [OP asked an episode-identification question on that show](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/243153/98028), based on the very dialogue that was mentioned in that question.

Answer (score 0):

This is *[Redakai: Conquer the Kairu](https://redapedia.fandom.com/wiki/Redapedia)*.

> The series revolves around Ky, a 15-year-old student of ancient martial arts, who embarks on an epic quest to find the Kairu, a primordial alien energy source. Aided by his friends Maya and Boomer, Ky travels the world searching for the Kairu while attempting to make sure that his extraterrestrial teenage alien adversaries don’t find it first...

The orange alien is [Mookee](https://redapedia.fandom.com/wiki/Mookee)

### Trailer

Found with a search for `"freeze ray" "blue attack"`, which took me to [this review](https://youtu.be/W1te3PFTLOQ) of the card game, and then it was just a matter of grabbing the wiki entry.

Comment: If so, it's a dupe https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161036/looking-for-the-name-of-a-card-battle-cartoon-show/161064?r=SearchResults#161064

Comment: The OP's other account has [asked a question on Redakai](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/243153/58193) now so presumably this is correct.