# Redakai episode when Boomer's magic wasn't working properly

Tags: episode-identification, redakai

In *Redakai: Conquer the Kairu* (the TV series), which episode was it when Boomer's magic didn't work properly, and he said:

> Freeze ray! What? Freeze ray is a blue attack, not a green one!

Answer (score 1):

Season 1, episode 18. It's about nine minutes into this video clip:

Comment: If this answer is correct, please upvote it and mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark beneath the voting buttons.